# tapestry palette with drag and drop option

Tags: drag-and-drop, tapestry, palette

I would like to know, if there is any simple way to make drag and drop palette in Tapestry 5 or two connected lists with drag an drop? I know how to do it in jQuery but I dont know hot to extract selected data from javascript to java when i do it in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble making palette work with objects, in my research i came across this [site](http://tapestry5-jquery.com/core/docsjquerypalette). Only palette for tapestry that seems remotely understandable to me.